# Loop only matching same symbol type instead of comparing them based on location in the string

Tags: ruby, regex, loops, recursion

We looked for even numbers of matching braces, but did not account for the location within the array. Like this:

```
def brace_count(brace_array)
    # ["{}[]()", "{}[]()"]

    brace_array.each do |braces|
        brace_chars_array = braces.split('')
        # ["{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")"]
        paren_count = 0
        brace_count = 0
        bracket_count = 0
        brace_chars_array.each do |char|
            if char == "[" || char == "]"
                bracket_count += 1
            elsif char == "{" || char == "}"
                brace_count += 1
            elsif char == "(" || char == ")"
                paren_count += 1
            end
        # brace_count = 2, paren_count = 2, bracket_count = 2
        if brace_count % 2 == 0 && paren_count  % 2 == 0 && bracket_count % 2 == 0
            puts 1
        else 
            puts 0
        end
    end
end
```

Does anyone know how to approach this? We couldn't figure out how to recursively call this. I figure regex isn't the right approach. It should return `1` if the braces match, but `0` if they don't, and if a different type of brace is in between two matching braces, the test should churn out `0`.

Example:

```
{{[]}} = 1 
{([[)]]} = 0 (Even though the brackets are all even numbers [1 open 1 close, just not ordered properly])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a LIFO stack to keep track of braces as you come across them. You can get this with an array just by pushing and popping it.

If you're just looking to verify that the braces are balanced, the simplest approach is to run through the string, stick opening braces on a stack, pop the stack when you come to a closing brace and verify that the closing brace matches the opening brace you just popped. Return 0 when they don't match, and if you get to the end of the string, return 1 if the stack is empty and 0 if it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Using String#count for this.

```
input_string.count(string_containing_chars_to_count)
```

It will massively shorten your code:

```
input = "{}[]()"
brackets, braces, parens = ['[]', '{}', '()'].map { |t| input.count t }     
#=> [2, 2, 2]
```

However, as a hint: You want to increment a counter each time you meet a '{' and decrement it each time you meet a '}', then check that the counter is at 0 when the string has ended. 
I'm sure you can figure it out from there!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you have strings with matching pairs of braces, brackets and parentheses.  If they always appear as pairs in your strings (not `"[{}]"`, for example), the problem is considerably simplifed.

Suppose you are processing the string:

```
str = "{}[]()"
```

Notice that

```
str.scan(/../) # => ["{}", "[]", "()"]
```

So you can do something like this:

```
str.strip.scan(/../).each do |s|
  case s
  when "{}"
    ..do something..
  when "[]"
    ..do something..
  when "()"
    ..do something..
  else
    .. raise an error..
  end
end
```

(I inserted `strip` between `str` and `scan` to strip any whitespace that might be at the beginning or end of the string before `scan` splits out the pairs.)

The advantage of working with pairs is that an error is flagged if you have an unmatched pair:

```
str = "{}[[()"
```

You don't have to check to determine if the number of `[` is the same as the number of `]`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your teacher is expecting something like this:

```
def brace_match?(chars_array)
  while ['{', '[', '('].include?(chars_array.first)
    opener = chars_array.shift
    return false unless brace_match?(chars_array)  # This is the recursive call (s)he mentioned.
    closer = chars_array.shift
    case opener
    when '['
      return false if closer != ']'
    when '{'
      return false if closer != '}'
    when '('
      return false if closer != ')'
    end
  end
  return chars_array.empty? || ['}', ']', ')'].include?(chars_array.first)
end

def brace_count(brace_array)
    # ["{}[]()", "{}[]()"]

    brace_array.each do |braces|
        brace_chars_array = braces.split('')
        # ["{", "}", "[", "]", "(", ")"]
        if brace_match?(brace_chars_array)
            puts 1
        else
            puts 0
        end
    end
end
```

This does the same thing but with somewhat compressed codes:

```
Braces = { '{' => '}', '[' => ']', '(' => ')' }

def brace_match?(chars_array)
  while Braces.keys.include?(chars_array.first)
    opener = chars_array.shift
    return false unless brace_match?(chars_array)  # This is the recursive call (s)he mentioned.
    return false unless chars_array.shift == Braces[opener]
  end
  return chars_array.empty? || Braces.values.include?(chars_array.first)
end
```